# Determining the location of magnetic moments

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

The magnetic moment of a closed current loop is $$\mathbf{m} = \frac{I}{2}\int\mathbf{r}\times d\mathbf{r}.$$  Note that $\mathbf{m}$ is independent of any coordinate frame.  How, then, does one determine the *location* of a magnetic moment?

Certainly the vector potential due to a magnetic dipole $$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{\mathbf{m}\times\mathbf{r}}{r^3}$$ *does* depend on the location of the coordinate frame, since $r$ is by definition the distance between the magnetic dipole and the target point, therefore it is important to know the location of the dipole (or the current loop we are approximating as a dipole).

How does one determine where to set the origin of the coordinate system so as to use the expression for $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})$ above, given an arbitrarily-shaped current loop?

Comment: You do realize that magnetic dipole potential is only a first term in multipole expansion for an arbitrary shaped loop? If you are neglecting terms smaller than $1/r^2$, then it does not matter where you place the origin, since corrections from that would only modify $1/r^3$ and higher terms.

Comment: Yes, I am approximating an arbitrarily-shaped current loop as a perfect magnetic dipole.  If the origin can be placed anywhere, then placing it a distance $R$ from the target means $A(r)\sim1/R^2$, while placing it at $10R$ means $A(r)\sim1/100R^2$.  The choice of origin thus matters, correct?

Comment: You are missing the point of asymptotic expansion. Dipole expansion is only valid as long as you can neglect the next term. If the loop of yours is located within, say, the region of size $l$, then dipole approximation would only work at a distances $r\gg l$ from this region. Varying the origin placement within that same region will gives you *relative* change of about $l/r$ so would also be negligible at the distances where dipole approximation starts working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above equation of $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})$ is not for arbitrary shape loop but for a point magnetic dipole. So the position of the dipole will be well-defined.

Added: When you look at points close to loop (close enough that you can not take it as point dipole) then above  $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})$ is not valid and in general it would be an integral over the loop

Comment: Hi Richard.  I am taking an arbitrarily-shaped current loop, and *approximating* it as a magnetic dipole.  Its magnetic dipole moment $\mathbf{m}$ is well-defined, but what about its position?

Comment: When you look at points close to loop (close enough that you can not take it as point dipole) then above $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})$ is not valid and in general it would be an integral over the loop.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  Your comment has answered my question.  Consider adding it to your answer :)